# How to properly use particles in translating the following sentence?

Tags: translation, particles

I'm still trying to figure out how to use two verbs together in Japanese. Like pairing the words "going" and "learn". Please excuse me for my beginner question, as this is my first time posting. I can read hiragana and katakana. I came here to ask if someone could translate the following sentence into Japanese. This will hopefully help me gain an understanding on how to use particles properly. Thanks!! "What language are you going to learn?"

Comment: We don't do translation requests here.  If you edit your question to show your work (i.e., how you think it might be translated, and how you'd put verbs together), you will receive more help.  Otherwise, it will probably be closed as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to learn the grammar of つもり to say this correctly.

- [How to Express Volition in Japanese: …（よ）う and つもりだ](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/how-to-express-volition/)
- [つもり (tsumori) expresses a plan or intention](https://japanesemeow.com/japanese-grammar-lessons/tsumori/)

> どんな言語【げんご】を学ぶ【まなぶ】つもりですか?
>   What language are you going to learn?

If you are trying to combine 行く【いく】 with another verb, then forget that approach. English "(be) going to" in "are you going to (verb)" is a special grammar pattern, and literal word-by-word translation will never work. Each language has its own way of expressing one's intention. This is not a problem of combining two verbs or picking a particle.

Answer (score 1):

「どんな（or,どの）言語{げんご}を学{まな}ぶつもりですか。」
「何語{なにご}を学ぶつもりですか。」
Both for the above are the same meaning.

English "be going to + verb" is translated in 「（Verb-dictionary form)つもりです。」  The nuance of 「…つもりです」 is close to "plan to / be planning to".
  Ex:
   I'm going to buy this. = (わたしは）これを買{か}うつもりです。
   I'm going to see the movie. = (わたしは）その映画{えいが}を見{み}るつもりです。